# I tried to deploy a smart contract with address argument in ropsten, but the account is complained to be invalid

Tags: deployment, truffle

```
const wallets = [accounts[2],accounts[3]];
const shares = [2,1];

    return deployer
        .then(() => {
            return deployer.deploy(
                Fund,
                wallets,
                shares
            );
        })
};
```

`wallets` and `shares` are arguments of the smart contract in the constructor:

```
constructor (address[] memory payees, uint256[] memory shares)
```

I think it cannot identify the accounts[2], accounts[3]. This has no problem in ganache, but it failed in Ropsten.

Comment: Can you post full migration code and the error that you got?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in ropsten, so after I changed them to address, it works.